# Script runs correctly from command line but not embedded in another script

Tags: linux, bash

when I use encpass from command line : no problem

```
#!/bin/sh
label=$1
. ./encpass.sh
password=$(get_secret  $label)
echo "passw $password
[dbadmin@luechdb61 scripts]$ ./secret.sh  dbllud1
passw Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[dbadmin@luechdb61 scripts]$ ./secret.sh  dbllud2
passw Tyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

password is correctly retrieved
now I call it from another script
......

```
    usr_name=$(echo ${server_name} |cut -d ':' -f3)
        echo "handling script_name ${Scr_nme} for server_name : ${srv_name=} dbname : ${db_name} "
        . ./encpass.sh
        password=$(get_secret ${usr_name})
...
```

in this case : I also echoed the input and is correct
but get_secret does not recognize this and wants to create a new entry although the entry is correctly displayed

```
[dbadmin@luechdb61 scripts]$ ./db2Deploy.sh -s scr.sql -m deploy.lst -e d
handling script_name scr.sql for server_name : luechdb61 dbname : IEEINT
xdbllud1x   <--- echo from script x${usr_name}x
Enter dbllud1:
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

what could be the reason for this ?
thanks for all answer
best regards, Guy

Comment: Suggestion for the future: provide always a complete working (simplified) code, not only spare snippets. How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a command, the standard input stream of that command is taken from the keyboard and the standard output and error stream go to the screen of the terminal.

```
echo "Hello world!"
```

With this command, "Hello world!" is displayed on the screen.

But when you execute the same command inside a `$(...)`, the standard input and output streams are in a subshell that doesn't interfere with the current shell connected to your keyboard and screen. In this case, the standard output is sent to the variable `usr_name`.

```
usr_name=$(echo "Hello world!")
```

With this command, you don't see anything at the screen, but if you want to display this message to the screen, you need to run:

```
echo "$usr_name"
```

A possible way to bypass this, is to sent the output to a special file called `/dev/tty`. So issuing:

```
usr_name=$(echo "Hello world!" > /dev/tty)
```

will leave the variable `$usr_name` empty and send "Hello world!" to the terminal, even if executed form the subshell. It is also possible to read a password from the subshell directly from the terminal. Try:

```
$(get_secret ${usr_name} < /dev/tty)
```

as far as I guess your code, since you don't provide the code of the function `get_secret ()` or of the command `get_secret`.

Comment: thanks for all update. The owner of encpass.sh recommended to add set -- before calling his encpass.sh.  this corrected the problem.    Best Regards, Guy